# How I can set visibility for view to some time?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, handler

I have an ugly method that could use some fixing. The problem is that I use the handler twice. I have a `textViewTitle` (`visibility = View.GONE`) and I should to show my view. With a delay of 1 second and after 5 seconds set `visibility = gone` back.

How I can do it? This is what I've tried so far:

```
private fun mechanics() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        textViewTitle.visibility = View.GONE
    }, 2000)
    someActions()
    Handler().postDelayed({
        textViewTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        someActions()    
    ,1100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've done some experimenting. This seems to work fine:

```
fixedRateTimer(initialDelay = 1000, period = 1) { println("hi"); this.cancel() }
fixedRateTimer(initialDelay = 5000, period = 1) { println("hi again"); this.cancel() }
//anything put here will run immediately, not after the timers
```

Just replace the `println()` with whatever code you want to execute. I know it's kind of messy, but it works fine.

If the timing isn't exact enough, I probably misunderstood your question, so just modify times appropriately. **Another issue would be that the script has to be manually ended, for some reason. If I figure out why, I'll update this answer.**

Comment: It has to be ended manually because you are starting a `TimerTask()` which executes periodically and doesn't end on it's own. It's a loop with delays

Comment: @Napster I called `this.cancel()` after the first iteration, which effectively ended itself. I waited a while to make sure of that. They didn't loop, the program just didn't end by itself.

Comment: I know `this.cancel()` does that, I thought that's what you meant by script has to be manually ended

Comment: @Napster I see. I mean that literally IntelliJ has the red box available in the top right corner, and it doesn't say `Process finished with exit code 0`.